# dev.modern.ie virtual machine licensing

Tags: legal

https://dev.modern.ie/ provides free VM image downloads for users to test their web applications in a virtualised environment. I'd like to know if the licensing for this supports commercial use, but I can't find anything to suggest that it does or does not on that site. The availability of MSDN subscriptions for use by testers is suggestive that licensing would be more stringent, but Microsoft is clearly taking a different approach more recently with the free almost fully featured Visual Studio.

There is a "license terms" document, here: http://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/release_notes_license_terms_1_5_15.pdf but I can't find anything in it to suggest what the license terms actually are. I'm hesitant to believe that a lack of specification regarding commercial use means that it's a free for all.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about web applications within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are an agency or a developer building websites you can use them in your regular development flow.

You cannot sell them or use them for something different than web testing (like develop windows apps). If you share your scenario I can verify if it is in the license terms or not. Page 5 of the document you've linked explains this.

Source: I'm the PM of https://dev.modern.ie and its tools

Comment: We are a large company, and would be using the software purely for internal testing purposes. For some reason I get the impression that this is closer to the offerings of BizSpark or similar, and was only valid for companies up to a certain size, or maybe only to certain startups. Free is a fairly vague word, and we really don't want to take any risks.

Comment: If it is for testing websites then it is OK. If you are going to test something else then it will not be OK.

Comment: Thanks - with regards to the section which says `You may install and use the software on one computer for use by one person at a time` - is this in reference to each company using it as an entity? If that's the case it's practically useless to us as we have so many people who would be looking to use such a solution... I'd probably be looking at having it run on up to 40-50 machines at any given time and at any moment it may be in use by that same number of people.

Comment: As long as you have one user per VM, which seems to be the case, then it is fine.